# Problems when running flutter on Ubuntu in VS code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I would like to run my first Flutter application on Ubuntu in Visual studio Code. I press F5 in main.dart and I got this error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:603 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:825 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/CMakeLists.txt:25 (pkg_check_modules)
```

How can I solve this, please? Or how can I at least see what package is missing?